# Java Jena SPARQL Query not retrieving results

Tags: java, sparql, jena, dbpedia

I am trying to use Jena in Java to run a SPARQL query and retrieve the results from a `.ttl` file. For some reason, the desired results are not being retrieved. I have looked at my SPARQL query and I am not sure where the error is, but no results are being delivered to my `ResultSet` object. Here is my code below:

```
BasicConfigurator.configure();
FileManager.get().addLocatorClassLoader(QuerySparql.class.getClassLoader());
Model model = FileManager.get().loadModel(My_Path//sample.ttl", "TTL");
String queryString = 
            "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\n" +
            "PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name>\n" +
            "PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>\n" +
            "PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>\n " +
            "SELECT ?team WHERE { \n" + 
            "?simeon foaf:name \"Simeon Ikudabo\"@en .\n" +
            "?simeon dbo:team ?team\n" +
            "}";
Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
try {
        ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
        while(results.hasNext()) {
            QuerySolution soln = results.nextSolution();
            Literal team = soln.getLiteral("team");
            System.out.println(team);
        }
    }
catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
}

System.out.println("Done");
```

And here is the output in the console, but it doesn't actually grab any of the results that I am looking for and skips the while loop altogether because there are no results in the `ResultSet`:

```
3 [main] DEBUG Jena  - Jena initialization
375 [main] DEBUG org.apache.jena.util.FileManager  - Add location: LocatorFile
377 [main] DEBUG org.apache.jena.util.FileManager  - Add location: ClassLoaderLocator
384 [main] DEBUG org.apache.jena.util.LocationMapper  - Failed to find configuration: file:location-mapping.rdf;file:location-mapping.n3;file:location-mapping.ttl;file:etc/location-mapping.rdf;file:etc/location-mapping.n3;file:etc/location-mapping.ttl
384 [main] DEBUG org.apache.jena.util.FileManager  - Add location: LocatorFile
395 [main] DEBUG org.apache.jena.util.FileManager  - Add location: LocatorURL
395 [main] DEBUG org.apache.jena.util.FileManager  - Add location: ClassLoaderLocator
423 [main] DEBUG org.apache.jena.riot.system.stream.JenaIOEnvironment  - Failed to find configuration: location-mapping.ttl;location-mapping.rdf;location-mapping.n3;etc/location-mapping.rdf;etc/location-mapping.n3;etc/location-mapping.ttl
1731 [main] DEBUG org.apache.jena.info  - System architecture: 64 bit
1862 [main] DEBUG org.apache.jena.info  - System architecture: 64 bit
1896 [main] DEBUG org.apache.jena.util.FileManager  - loadModel(My_Path//sample.ttl, TTL)
1897 [main] DEBUG org.apache.jena.riot.system.stream.StreamManager  - Not mapped: My_Path//sample.ttl
1951 [main] DEBUG org.apache.jena.riot.system.stream.StreamManager  - Found: My_Path//sample.ttl (LocatorFile)
2633 [main] DEBUG org.apache.jena.shared.LockMRSW  - Lock : main
2638 [main] DEBUG org.apache.jena.shared.LockMRSW  - Lock : main
Done
```

As you can see, I create the variable `?team`, which is a `dbpedia.org/ontology/team` in my local dbpedia turtle file. `?simeon` in this example is the athlete that is being looked up, and Simeon will reflect the `foaf:name "Simeon Ikudabo"@en`. My last triple statement is `?simeon dbo:team ?team`. This should find dbpedia ontology team value that corresponds with Simeon Ikudabo. For some reason however, the `ResultSet` does not retrieve this value. I have looked online at what could be wrong with my query, but I am not sure what the issue could be from my research. Here is my `.ttl` file with the data, and it APPEARS to be formatted properly:

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Simeon_Ikudabo> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/team> 
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Indiana_Hoosiers> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Simeon_Ikudabo> <http://www.xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name> "Simeon Ikudabo"@en .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Nick_Mangeri> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/team> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Akron_Zips> .
<http://dbepdia.org/resource/Nick_Mangeri> <http://www.xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name> "Nick Mangeri"@en .
```

I also accounted for the possibility of an IO issue, but when I simply read the model in Java it seems to be getting the correct IO from the file. Here is my code for simply reading the model:

```
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
model.read("My_Path//sample.ttl", "TURTLE");
model.write(System.out);
```

And here is the output:

```
0 [main] DEBUG Jena  - Jena initialization
417 [main] DEBUG org.apache.jena.util.FileManager  - Add location: LocatorFile
419 [main] DEBUG org.apache.jena.util.FileManager  - Add location: ClassLoaderLocator
428 [main] DEBUG org.apache.jena.util.LocationMapper  - Failed to find configuration: file:location-mapping.rdf;file:location-mapping.n3;file:location-mapping.ttl;file:etc/location-mapping.rdf;file:etc/location-mapping.n3;file:etc/location-mapping.ttl
428 [main] DEBUG org.apache.jena.util.FileManager  - Add location: LocatorFile
431 [main] DEBUG org.apache.jena.util.FileManager  - Add location: LocatorURL
431 [main] DEBUG org.apache.jena.util.FileManager  - Add location: ClassLoaderLocator
457 [main] DEBUG org.apache.jena.riot.system.stream.JenaIOEnvironment  - Failed to find configuration: location-mapping.ttl;location-mapping.rdf;location-mapping.n3;etc/location-mapping.rdf;etc/location-mapping.n3;etc/location-mapping.ttl
1793 [main] DEBUG org.apache.jena.info  - System architecture: 64 bit
1912 [main] DEBUG org.apache.jena.info  - System architecture: 64 bit
2254 [main] DEBUG org.apache.jena.riot.system.stream.StreamManager  - Not mapped: My_Path//sample.ttl
2255 [main] DEBUG org.apache.jena.riot.system.stream.StreamManager  - open(My_Path//sample.ttl)
2255 [main] DEBUG org.apache.jena.riot.system.stream.StreamManager  - Not mapped: My_Path//sample.ttl
2288 [main] DEBUG org.apache.jena.riot.system.stream.StreamManager  - Found: My_Path//sample.ttl (LocatorFile)
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:j.0="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/"
    xmlns:j.1="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/"
    xmlns:j.2="http://www.xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/">
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Nick_Mangeri">
    <j.1:team rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Akron_Zips"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://dbepdia.org/resource/Nick_Mangeri">
    <j.2:name xml:lang="en">Nick Mangeri</j.2:name>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Simeon_Ikudabo">
    <j.2:name xml:lang="en">Simeon Ikudabo</j.2:name>
    <j.0:team rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Indiana_Hoosiers"/>
 </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

So I know that Jena can read the file. I created a SIMILAR query using the Virtuoso SPARQL endpoint for DBpedia and consistently get the proper results. He is a similar query that I ran as a test from the Virtuoso SPARQL endpoint for DBpedia:

```
prefix dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix db: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT ?draftTeam WHERE{
?kobe dbpedia-owl:draftTeam ?draftTeam .
?kobe foaf:name "Kobe Bryant"@en .
}
```

I know that the Virtuoso SPARQL endpoint is slightly different from the Apache Jena SPARQL query, but it is the same general syntax. I am stumped as to why I cannot execute a query in Jena.

Comment: well, your FOAF prefix declaration is wrong: `PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name>` - it should be `PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>`, i.e. without the property `name`

Comment: @AKSW thanks. I looked at that earlier and that didn’t fix the issue.

Comment: what does that mean? it doesn't work even with the the correct prefix declaration? by the way, it would be good if you edit your question and fix the typos even if it doesn't solve the issue - at least it would avoid others finding the same problems

Comment: please double check data + query. In the query you used `PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name>`. In the data you used `http://www.xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/` - both are clearly wrong, the former has to get rid of `name`, the latter is wrong because of the `www.` which makes no sense. FOAF: `http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/`

Comment: @AKSW I meant that changing it to *<http://xlmns.com/foaf/0.1/>* did NOT solve the issue.

Comment: it has to be `http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/`! and in both, query **and** data. Your data uses `http://www.xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/`, remove `www.`. Your query uses `http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name`, remove `name`

Comment: @SimeonIkudabo In your original query, you have the prefix declaration `PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name>`, so when you use `foaf:name` in the query, you're getting the URI `http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/namename`. All you need to do is fix that prefix (and use it consistently in the data, too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. Here is a sample of the code below:

```
BasicConfigurator.configure();
FileManager.get().addLocatorClassLoader(QuerySparql.class.getClassLoader());
Model model = FileManager.get().loadModel("My_Path//sample.ttl", "TTL");
String queryString = 
            "PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/resource> \n" +
            "SELECT ?meshId WHERE{ \n" + 
            "?autism <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name> \"Autism\"@en .\n" +
            "?autism <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/meshId> ?meshId \n" +
            "}";

Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);

ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
if(results.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println("has results!");
}
else {
    System.out.println("No Results!");
}

while(results.hasNext()) {
    QuerySolution soln = results.nextSolution();
    Literal r = soln.getLiteral("meshId");
    System.out.println(r);
}
```

The error appears to have been within the query. I needed to use the full URL that is in the dbpedia file for my query. In dbpedia file the url looks like this:

```
<http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name> "Autism"@en .
```

Using that URL within the actual query like this:

```
"?autism <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name> \"Autism\"@en .\n
```

ended up solving the issue. The prefix that I used earlier within the query did not directly match the prefix that was in the dbpedia file. So the prefix:

```
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
```

will not work. Instead, I need to put the URL that directly matches the one found in the dbpedia file.

Comment: what? did you read my last comment? the problem is that in the data the prefix was `http://www.xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/` and in the query you used `http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name` - **both do not match** and moreover, **both are wrong** - the correct one is `http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/` - the solution is clearly **not** using a full URI but fixing the prefix declarations in data and query.

Comment: @AKSW I checked and using the full URI is what fixed it in this case. I changed the prefix to **PREFIX foaf:<http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>** and that did not work. Removing the prefix and simply using **<http://xmlns/foaf/0.1/name> “Name”@en** within the body of the query worked. As you mentioned, **http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>** is the correct solution, however, in Jena when working with the dbpedia mappingbased_properties dataset, that solution will not work. For example I’d i used that Prefix **foaf:name “name”@en**would NOT work in the query body.

Comment: Well, I don't think you fixed the issues then. To clarify, I tried it on my computer with Apache Jena and it works as expected: here is the **fixed query**: `PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
 PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
 SELECT ?team WHERE {
?simeon foaf:name "Simeon Ikudabo"@en .
?simeon dbo:team ?team
}`

Comment: and the **fixed data (part 1)**: `<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:j.0="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/"
    xmlns:j.1="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/"
    xmlns:j.2="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/">
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Nick_Mangeri">
    <j.1:team rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Akron_Zips"/>
</rdf:Description>`

Comment: **fixed data (part 2)**: `<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Nick_Mangeri">
    <j.2:name xml:lang="en">Nick Mangeri</j.2:name>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Simeon_Ikudabo">
    <j.2:name xml:lang="en">Simeon Ikudabo</j.2:name>
    <j.0:team rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Indiana_Hoosiers"/>
 </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>`

Comment: @SimeonIkudabo - You found a workaround, not a solution. (Typos and other errors are present in every comment you've posted, as well as your original question.) Your workaround took a different route, which removed those errors -- it did not correct the actual errors in your initial effort. The corrections to that original effort provided by **AKSW** and **joshua-taylor** would also have brought success, if applied properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your data has the triple

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Simeon_Ikudabo> <http://dbepdia.org/ontology/team> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Indiana_Hoosiers> .
```

And there's a typo: `dbepdia` instead of `dbpedia` in the property. I found this when I noticed in the printed model that there were two namespaces:

```
xmlns:j.0="http://dbepdia.org/ontology/"
xmlns:j.1="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/"
```

Comment: Thank you for catching that typo. I edited my question and fixed that. I am still getting the same error.